# Sequelize many to many relationship

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I need some help to get my head around the sequelize many to many relationship.

I have to models, clients and services (many to many). Now I would like to load all services offered by one client (via client id). How does the condition with include have to look like to achieve this?

Service:

```
var Service = sequelize.define('service', {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
      allowNull: false
    }
  },{
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate:function(models){
          Service.belongsToMany(models.client, { through: 'client_services' });
          Service.hasMany(models.rule, { foreignKey: 'service_id' })
      }
    }
  });
```

Client:

```
 var Client = sequelize.define('client', {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
      allowNull: false
    },
    company: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false
    },
    vendor: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    consumer: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: true
    },
    address_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    }
  },{
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate:function(models){
          Client.hasMany(models.service, { through: 'client_services'});
      }
    }
  });
```

In my Controller (doesn't work err: [Error: client (client) is not associated to service!]):

```
var condition = {
      where: { 'client.id': req.user.client_id },
      include: [{ model: Client, as: 'client' }]
    }
Service.findAll(condition)
.then(responseWithResult(res))
```

Comment: Try using `hasManyAndBelongsTo`

Comment: Thx for the answer. Can you post a link to the docs?

Comment: Did that actually work? I just found a reference to `hasManyAndBelongsTo` in some code on the sequelize Github repo, but I can't find a reference to it in any docs.  I'll look again.

Comment: You don't mean "belongsToMany" by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the where clause needs to be in the include with the model:

```
var condition = {
      include: [{ model: Client, where: { 'id': req.user.client_id } }]
    }
Service.findAll(condition)
.then(responseWithResult(res))
```